# SQLAlchemy weird joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psql

I want to never automatically load the `user` ralation when fetching `UserLocation` or `location` when fetching `User`.

I want to `JOIN` the tables when specified with `.join` or with `options(joinedLoad)` and I want to be able to filter on the joined table with like `.filter(models.User.title != None)`.

I want to do this because I think this is the best performing method to minimise the query amount.

I followed: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result

When I try to eager load with:

```py
return db\
        .query(models.UserLocation) \
        .join(models.UserLocation.user) \
        .filter(models.User.title != None) \
        .options(contains_eager(models.UserLocation.user)) \
        .all()
```

I get this error:

```
server-aws - ERROR - Caught exception for path /nearby
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 327, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.comparator, key)
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute '__name__'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chalice/app.py", line 1756, in _get_view_function_response
    response = view_function(**function_args)
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/chalicelib/api_nearby.py", line 22, in nearby
    nearby_users = crud.nearby.get_nearby_users(db.get_db(), u.uid, schemas.UserLocationGet(
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/chalicelib/crud/nearby.py", line 24, in get_nearby_users
    .options(contains_eager(models.UserLocation.user)) \
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 1193, in __call__
    self.name = name = fn.__name__
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 329, in __getattr__
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/theobouwman/dev/projects/meet/server-aws/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with UserLocation.user has an attribute '__name__'
192.168.178.16 - - [23/Nov/2021 17:54:48] "GET /nearby HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

These are my models.

```py
Base = declarative_base(cls=(JsonSerializableBase,))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    uid = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    phone = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    instagram = Column(String, nullable=True)
    linkedin = Column(String, nullable=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=True)
    profile_image_url = Column(String, nullable=True, default='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Circle-icons-profile.svg/1200px-Circle-icons-profile.svg.png') # todo: default
    location = relationship("UserLocation", back_populates="user", uselist=False, lazy='noload')
    permission_verified = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    permission_business_profile = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


class UserLocation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_locations"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    geo = Column(Geography(geometry_type='POINT'))
    latitude = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    longitude = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey(f'{User.__tablename__}.uid'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="location", lazy='joined', innerjoin=True, foreign_keys=[user_id])
```

Why is this code producing 2 `from`s?

```py
return db\
        .query(models.UserLocation) \
        .filter(models.User.title != None) \
        .filter(models.UserLocation.user_id != uid) \
        .filter(models.UserLocation.timestamp >= datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=minutes)) \
        .all()
```

Produced sql:

```sql
SELECT user_locations.id                   AS user_locations_id,
       ST_AsBinary(user_locations.geo)     AS user_locations_geo,
       user_locations.latitude             AS user_locations_latitude,
       user_locations.longitude            AS user_locations_longitude,
       user_locations.timestamp            AS user_locations_timestamp,
       user_locations.user_id              AS user_locations_user_id,
       users_1.uid                         AS users_1_uid,
       users_1.phone                       AS users_1_phone,
       users_1.name                        AS users_1_name,
       users_1.instagram                   AS users_1_instagram,
       users_1.linkedin                    AS users_1_linkedin,
       users_1.title                       AS users_1_title,
       users_1.profile_image_url           AS users_1_profile_image_url,
       users_1.permission_verified         AS users_1_permission_verified,
       users_1.permission_business_profile AS users_1_permission_business_profile
FROM users,
     user_locations
         JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.uid = user_locations.user_id
WHERE users.title IS NOT NULL
  AND user_locations.user_id != % (user_id_1)s AND user_locations.timestamp >= %(timestamp_1)s
```

And why is this code (added join) producing 2 joins:

```py
return db\
        .query(models.UserLocation) \
        .join(models.UserLocation.user) \
        .filter(models.User.title != None) \
        .filter(models.UserLocation.user_id != uid) \
        .filter(models.UserLocation.timestamp >= datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=minutes)) \
        .all()
```

Produced sql:

```sql
SELECT user_locations.id                   AS user_locations_id,
       ST_AsBinary(user_locations.geo)     AS user_locations_geo,
       user_locations.latitude             AS user_locations_latitude,
       user_locations.longitude            AS user_locations_longitude,
       user_locations.timestamp            AS user_locations_timestamp,
       user_locations.user_id              AS user_locations_user_id,
       users_1.uid                         AS users_1_uid,
       users_1.phone                       AS users_1_phone,
       users_1.name                        AS users_1_name,
       users_1.instagram                   AS users_1_instagram,
       users_1.linkedin                    AS users_1_linkedin,
       users_1.title                       AS users_1_title,
       users_1.profile_image_url           AS users_1_profile_image_url,
       users_1.permission_verified         AS users_1_permission_verified,
       users_1.permission_business_profile AS users_1_permission_business_profile
FROM user_locations
         JOIN users ON users.uid = user_locations.user_id
         JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.uid = user_locations.user_id
WHERE users.title IS NOT NULL
  AND user_locations.user_id != % (user_id_1)s AND user_locations.timestamp >= %(timestamp_1)s
```

Comment: The last 2 are a result of using `lazy='joined'` as the default in `UserLocation.user`. Filling the relationship is not automatically done from a join added to the query, you must use `contains_eager` to "override" the default strategy. This is so that it works by default even if you were for example trying to use one join to do filtering, but still wanted to load all related entities.

Comment: @IljaEverilä is it possible to to containers_eager when setting lazy to noload? That is what I actually want

Comment: Yes that should work. The option defined in the query overrides the default in the relationship.

Comment: @IljaEverilä this `
db\
        .query(models.UserLocation) \
        .join(models.UserLocation.user) \
        .options(contains_eager(models.UserLocation.user)) \
        .all()
` created this error:
`
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with UserLocation.user has an attribute '__name__'

`

Comment: I added the base class definition @IljaEverilä